# Spring Boot Static Resources From Controllers and Other Classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've been trying to solve this issue and I can't find the answer.

I've been having to use `src/main/resources/public/whatever...` in order to access static resources from class files. I was under the impression that if you use `/static /public /resources...` that Spring Boot already has those paths configured.

I'm lost at this point and not sure how I can access these files without having to prepend `src/main/resources/public.`

**EDIT**

Based on the suggestions regarding the static content, I created a private directory to protect files etc... that I don't want publicly available. And left css, images, etc... in the /public folder.

Thank you all for the suggestions and recommendations, I appreciate it!

Comment: What do you mean by "access"? What's your configuration?

Comment: to read a file, write, etc... in order to get to the resources directory I was having to use src/main/resources... I only really discovered the issue when I generated the war file and everything broke. I am using my answer below and it is working as expected.

Comment: You can't write to that directory safely, even with your answer. Write somewhere else, preferably configurable.

Answer (score 1):

After more searching I ran across an example that used the ClassLoader. I've only been using Spring for a short time and not aware of all the tools that are available, there might be a better way than this; if so please tell let me know.

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader()
new File(classLoader.getResource('public/file-name-or-directory').getFile())
```

So far it looks like it's working, I need to do some further testing and will post back if any issues.

Answer (score 1):

The directories you list, `/static`,  `/public` and `/resources`, are for [static content](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content) that will be served up by a web-application. Things like javascript files and images that will always be the same no matter who requests them and when, as opposed to JSPs for example that need to be processed on the server per request.

If you need to access a configured property in one of your Java classes (it must be a Spring bean), then you can put it in your `application.properties` file, and have Spring inject it using the `@Value` annotation.

Example code from [Spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config):

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.*
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.*

@Component
public class MyBean {

    @Value("${name}")
    private String name;

    // ...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot expect you to use for content served directly
src/main/resources/static

and to use for templating
src/main/resources/templates